# Using http get with body in angular

Tags: angular, http

Is it possible to send body using angular http `GET`? So I could have  API that requires query params and body at the same time?
So i have "dateReadyFrom" and "dateReadyTo" as queryParam and array of string "Products" as a body.

Comment: You can not send body but you can send data using `URL parameters`.

Comment: So i'm sending with HttpParams, but server requires body too.

Comment: Are you sure http request is of `GET` type?

Comment: Yeah there is couple filters two of them just URL param and rest of them must be in body.

Comment: Could you add some details to your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
dataReadyFormEnconde=encode(dateReadyFrom);
dateReadyToEncode=encode(dateReadyTo);

GET
/services?dateReadyFrom=dataReadyFormEnconde&dateReadTo=dateReadyToEncode
```